# Bounding max row sum of $(I-A)^{-1}$ given max row sum of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the $N \times N$ matrix $A$ with all nonnegative entries and with row sums all strictly less than $\alpha$, and assume that $\alpha < 1.$  Is it true that the max row sum (or perhaps max column sum?) of $(I-A)^{-1}$ is bounded by $1/(1-\alpha)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, the maximal sum of the absolute values of the row entries of $(I - A)^{-1}$ is bounded above by $\frac 1{1 - \alpha}$. To prove this, note that
$$
\|A\|_\infty = \max_{i=1,\dots,N}\sum_{j=1}^N |a_{ij}|
$$
defines a (submultiplicative) matrix norm. From the fact that $\|A\|_\infty < \alpha < 1$, we can deduce that the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) $\sum_{j=0}^\infty A^j$ converges to $(I - A)^{-1}$. Thus, we have
$$
\left\|(I - A)^{-1}\right\|_\infty = 
\left\|\sum_{j=0}^\infty A^j \right\|_\infty \leq \sum_{j=0}^\infty \|A\|_\infty^j < \sum_{j=0}^\infty \alpha^j = \frac 1{1 - \alpha}.
$$